# Maya Python change current renderer in render setting

Tags: python, maya, pymel

How to change current renderer in maya by python commands.
for example : "maya software" to "mental ray" or vice versa
any python or pymel command.?

```
import pymel.core as pm
import maya.cmds as cmds
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
```

## Switch to mental ray

```
cmds.setAttr("defaultRenderGlobals.currentRenderer", "mentalRay", type="string")
```

## Switch to maya software

```
cmds.setAttr("defaultRenderGlobals.currentRenderer", "mayaSoftware", type="string")
```

Comment: How do I save the rendered image to a jpeg format using python?

Comment: import pymel.core as pm
rendernode = pm.PyNode('defaultRenderGlobals')
rendernode.setAttr('imageFormat', 8)

Comment: if you want to convert image format through python than go with FFmpeg https://ffmpeg.org/

Comment: What are the different numbers for the imageFormat? I noticed that people usually use 51 which is exr

Comment: I also noticed that when I save the image using python by pm.render() the resulted image is much darker than if I saved it using Maya GUI. Is there a way to get the same result as Maya GUI?