# Change Current Render Engine to V-Ray using Python in maya 2022

Tags: python, python-3.x, maya

I'm just trying to change the current renderer in render settings to V-Ray in maya.

I followed this : [Maya Python change current renderer in render setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37407776/maya-python-change-current-renderer-in-render-setting)
But it's not working with V-Ray option

I also tried this :

```py
import maya.cmds as cmds

# ensure plugins are loaded
cmds.loadPlugin("vrayformaya", quiet=True)
cmds.loadPlugin("vrayvolumegrid", quiet=True)

# auto load
cmds.pluginInfo("vrayformaya", edit=True, autoload=True)
cmds.pluginInfo("vrayvolumegrid", edit=True, autoload=True)

# edit attribs
cmds.setAttr("defaultRenderGlobals.currentRenderer", l=False)  
cmds.setAttr("defaultRenderGlobals.currentRenderer", "V-Ray", type="string")

# Recreate the render window to refresh them
if cmds.window("unifiedRenderGlobalsWindow", exists=True):
    cmds.deleteUI("unifiedRenderGlobalsWindow")
mel.eval("unifiedRenderGlobalsWindow")
```

And i don't know why, but this code works for 'arnold' but not for 'V-Ray', in this line

```py
cmds.setAttr("defaultRenderGlobals.currentRenderer", "V-Ray", type="string")
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to read the correct value when you manually switch to VRay:

```py
print(cmds.getAttr("defaultRenderGlobals.currentRenderer"))
```

Then when you know the correct name, you can use it in your code:

```py
cmds.setAttr("defaultRenderGlobals.currentRenderer", "vray", type="string")
```

Comment: Thank you it's works !
It was a mistake on my part, thank you for your tip.